# oracle sql precision,scale ,insert calculate and drop

Tags: sql, oracle

```
table = mytable
temp col = tempcol
col = mycol
```

currently contains 5000 rows various values from 99999.99999 to 0.00001

I need to keep the data create a script to create a temp column,round the values to 7,3 update mycol to a null value, modify my column from 10,5 to 7,3 return the data to mycol, drop the temp column. Job done.

so far

```
SELECT mycol
INTO tempcol
FROM mytable

update mytable set mycol = null

alter table mytable modify mycol number (7,3)

SELECT tempcol
INTO mycol
FROM mytable

drop tempcol
```

can you please fill in the missing gaps are direct me to a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first of all a `NUMBER(10,5)` can store results from -99999 to 99999 while `NUMBER(7,3)` interval is only [-9999,9999] so you will potentially encounter conversion errors. You probably want to change the column into a `NUMBER(8,3)`.

Now your plan seems sound: you can not reduce the precision or the scale of a column while there is data in that column, so you will store data into a temporary column. I would do it like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE mytable (mycol NUMBER(10,5));     
Table created

SQL> /* populate table */
  2  INSERT INTO mytable
  3     (SELECT dbms_random.value(0, 1e10)/1e5
  4        FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1e3);     
1000 rows inserted

SQL> /* new temp column */
  2  ALTER TABLE mytable ADD (tempcol NUMBER(8,3));     
Table altered

SQL> /* copy data to temp */
  2  UPDATE mytable
  3     SET tempcol = mycol,
  4         mycol = NULL;     
1000 rows updated

SQL> ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY (mycol NUMBER(8,3));     
Table altered

SQL> UPDATE mytable
  2     SET mycol = tempcol;     
1000 rows updated

SQL> /* cleaning */
  2  ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN tempcol;
Table altered
```

Comment: This looks good but where does the rounding of the current values occur or will the happen automatically, to clarify i am going from 5 decimal places rounding the number and then the updated values will be 3 decimal places.